# using sql dependency without CREATE PROCEDURE permission

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am trying to start an SqlDependency with `SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionString)`.

But getting an error:
*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll. Additional information: CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'HMS'.*

My constraint is that i have to use Sql Dependency without the permission for CREATE PROCEDURE

I am trying to detect changes in a specific table. This is the rest of my code:

```
Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

command.CommandText = "AppointmentDependency"
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HEID", sHEID)

Using command

    Dim dependency As New SqlClient.SqlDependency(command)
    AddHandler dependency.OnChange, AddressOf OnDependencyChange

End Using
```